# Intuition about non-standard product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Given a set of $m$-dimensional complex vectors $\{v_{11},v_{12},..,v_{nn}\}$, does there exist a set of $m\times m$ complex matrices $\{F_1,F_2,...,F_n\}$ such that

\begin{equation}
(F_a)_{ij} = \sum_k (F_b)_{ik}(v_{ij})_k(F_c)_{kj}
\end{equation}
holds for all $a,b,c\leq n$. This system of equations pops up as a consistency condition in some algebraic/category theoretic framework.  These equations are fairly general and I do not expect a full answer to exist, but I am interested in the more general structure of these equations.

The above equations look like some non-standard matrix product form, where if all $(v_{ij})_k = 1$ would result in $F_a = F_b F_c$. Does this form exist in the literature and if so are there any useful properties of this non-standard product? More interestingly can we write this form in a more standard linear algebra form in terms of the matrices?

Comment: Your expression can be rewritten as $(F_a)_{ij}=e_i^TF_b\mathrm{diag}_k\{(v_{ij})_k)\}F_ce_j$ where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ is the natural basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$. The difficulty in writing a compact form is that the middle term depends on $(i,j)$. You may also look at multilinear algebra.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion notation there are $n*n$ vectors which I label by two indices, every vector of this list has $m$ elements. For example take $n=2$ and $m=3$, then I would have 4 vectors which I call $v_{11},v_{12},v_{21}$ and $v_{22}$. each of these four vectors have 3 components, namely $(v_{11})_1,(v_{11})_2,(v_{11})_3$ and so on.